# docker-compose command overrides container name specified in the yaml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Why does docker compose override the container name?
The container is being created with name 'redis_redis-server_1' (not 'redis-server' as expected). Container name specified in the yml file is 'redis-server'.

Content of docker-compose.yml. The specified container name is **redis-server**:

```
version: '3'
services:
   redis-server:
      image: 'redis'
```

Before running docker-compose:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
26e88fcdbd37   af81c4b35bd6   "java -jar drivebox.…"   47 hours ago   Exited (143) 5 hours ago             stupefied_poitras
```

docker-compose output:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "redis_default" with the default driver
Creating redis_redis-server_1 ... done
Attaching to redis_redis-server_1
redis-server_1  | 1:C 04 Nov 2022 14:11:52.365 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-server_1  | 1:C 04 Nov 2022 14:11:52.365 # Redis version=7.0.5, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-server_1  | 1:C 04 Nov 2022 14:11:52.365 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-server_1  | 1:M 04 Nov 2022 14:11:52.366 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis-server_1  | 1:M 04 Nov 2022 14:11:52.366 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-server_1  | 1:M 04 Nov 2022 14:11:52.366 # Server initialized
redis-server_1  | 1:M 04 Nov 2022 14:11:52.367 * Ready to accept connections
```

The container name is overridden to **redis_redis-server_1**:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
5a689b1c6abb   redis     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   6379/tcp   redis_redis-server_1
```

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

Comment: You did not specify the `container_name` in the file you posted. Additionally, the service name is `redis-server`, not `redis_server`. I do not understand. In the spirit of this forum, please ask a question.

Comment: "Why does docker compose override the container name?" - It does not!  that is the service name; container name (aka last column on docker ps), must be specified in compose with **container_name**, otherwise it gets automatically generated

Answer (score 0):

Unless the [`container_name` parameter](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name) has been specified for the service, the container name will be generated with the format [`<project>_<service>_<index>`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/release-notes/#1232) where

- `<project>` is the name of the docker-compose project (taken from the name of the directory where `docker-compose.yml` is located) (in your case `redis`)
- `<service>` is the name of the service the container has created from (in your case `redis-server`)
- `<index>` is the index of the container amongst the containers created from the same service (this will be 1 in Docker Compose or N>=1 in Docker Swarm)